# How do I add a namespace when creating an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have to create an XML document in C#.

The root element has to look like this:

```
<valuation-request 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="valuations.xsd">
```

I'm using the following

```
XmlElement root = X.CreateElement("valuation-request");
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
root.SetAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "valuations.xsd");
```

However this produces

```
<valuation-request 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     noNamespaceSchemaLocation="valuations.xsd"> //missing the xsi:
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the overload of [SetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec5ak8h6.aspx), that takes namespace as well:

```
root.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", 
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 
    "valuations.xsd"
);
```

Comment: I'm using root.SetAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "valuations.xsd");. how would you suggest it should look?

Comment: try this root.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "valuations.xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

Comment: That returns <valuation-request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d1p1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d1p1="valuations.xsd">

Comment: I swapped them round to look like             root.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "valuations.xsd"); ...bish bash bosh.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

With writer you add it like this:

```
var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = " ",
            NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)
        };

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\test.xml", writerSettings);
writer.WriteStartDocument(false);
writer.WriteStartElement("valuation-request");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null, "http://www.gzs.si/e-poslovanje/sheme/eSLOG_1-5_EnostavniRacun.xsd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have encountered same issue. To resolve it, I've just add the follow line:

```
XmlAttribute noNamespaceSchemaLocationAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Comment: that works just fine on my Code. Important to me was the XMLSchema-instance part